# Gibt es ein Wort dafür, wenn jemand nichts riechen kann?

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es ein Wort, das die Fragezeichen ersetzen kann?

```
sehen      blind
hören      taub
fühlen     taub
sprechen   stumm
riechen    ???
```

Comment: _Sprechen_ ist, im Gegensatz zu den vier anderen, kein Verb für eine Sinneswahrnehmung.

Comment: Definitiv nicht _geruchslos_ oder _ruchlos_. Zu _schmecken_ gibt es auch keine nicht-fachsprachliche Bezeichnung.

Comment: @Crissov: Dass es ein Äquivalent im Fall des Schmeckens nicht gibt, ist mit auch aufgefallen, nachdem ich die Frage gestellt hatte. Schätze, man kann sich dort mit Ähnlichem behelfen wie für riechen.

Comment: Und da wären wir dann bei der [Ageusie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschmacksstörung), wenn der Geschmackssinn komplett abhanden gekommen ist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich würde den Begriff geruchsblind verwenden, auch wenn er fachlich nicht korrekt ist (siehe auch Beispiel unten).

Analog Farbenblind ist es auch kein Ausdruck dafür, dass man nichts riechen kann, sondern eher ein Ausdruck dafür, dass man manche Gerüche nicht riechen kann.

Riechstörung wäre eine andere Möglichkeit, auch wenn es nicht unbedingt ausdrückt, dass man nichts mehr riechen kann.

Beispiel einer Verwendung:

> Allergien, Viren oder Verletzungen können eine Anosmie auslösen Professor Hüttenbrink, wie entsteht eine Geruchsblindheit?
>
> Karl-Bernd Hüttenbrink: Stop! Geruchsblind ist der falsche Ausdruck. Man sagt ja auch nicht gehörblind. Blindheit betrifft den Sehsinn, beim Hören spricht man von Hörstörungen, die bis zur Taubheit reichen können. Und es gibt Riechstörungen, die in einer sogenannten Anosmie gipfeln können. Das ist der Fachausdruck für den Zustand, in dem ein Patient gar nicht mehr riechen kann.

Quelle: [Sinnverlust: Krankheitsbild mit vielen Ursachen, Kölner Stadt-Anzeige](http://www.ksta.de/panorama/sinnverlust-krankheitsbild-mit-vielen-ursachen,15189504,23206564.html)

Comment: Aus dem Gefühl heraus hätte ich eher zu "taub" als zu "blind" gegriffen. Man findet im Internet übrigens die Begriffe "geruchsblind", "riechblind", "geruchstaub" und "riechtaub".

Comment: @Em1 _geruchstaub_ hab ich zunächst als _Geruch-Staub_ gelesen ;)

Comment: Dazu fällt mir nur ein: "Einer Sprache, in der die Nase läuft und die Füße riechen, sollte man nicht trauen" ;)

Comment: Der gute Professor liegt daneben! Natürlich gibt es "gehörblind" nicht - weil es dafür eben das Wort "taub" gibt! Es gibt auch das Wort "sehtaub" nicht, weil wir "blind" dafür haben. Aber für "kann nicht riechen" gibt es eben *kein* Wort - und die Analogie "wie Blind(heit) beim Sehen, aber eben für das Riechen" erschließt sich ohne weiteres bei "geruchsblind". Um "Anosmie" ohne Pschyrembel zu verstehen, braucht man schon das große Latinum und Graecum.

Comment: Die Formulierung "liegt daneben" ist natürlich der falsche Ausdruck für diesen Lapsus in der kritischen Attestation eines kreativen Juxtapositums.

Answer (score 16):

Unter [Anosmie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosmie) versteht man das Fehlen des Geruchssinns. Das Adjektiv dazu ist *anosmisch*. Die Person wird als *Anosmatiker* bezeichnet.

Comment: Allerdings definitiv nicht auf demselben sprachlichen Niveau wie _blind_ oder _stumm_. +1 für fachlich richtig, aber niemand sollte erwarten, im Alltag verstanden zu werden, wenn er _anosmisch_ benutzt.

Comment: Das wird bestimmt *an-osmisch* getrennt, oder?

Comment: @Jan: Prinzipiell ja.

Comment: Das sind medizinische Fachbegriffe und keine Begriffe der Alltagssprache. »Können Sie mir bitte sagen, wonach dieses Schnitzel riecht? Ich bin leider anosmisch.« wird man kaum hören, und wenn es doch mal gesagt werden sollte, wird es von so gut wie niemandem verstanden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Stimmt, man würde es umschreiben, denn es gibt **keinen** Begriff der Alltagssprache. Und nein, auch die Begriffe "geruchsblind" oder "geruchstaub" gehören nicht zur Alltagssprache und sind ausschließlich aufgrund der Analogie zu sehblind und hörtaub bzw. gefühlstaub verständlich. Aber die Frage besagt nicht, dass gesucht wird, wie man in der Alltagssprache sich klar verständlich ausdrückt, sondern ob es einen Begriff gibt, der die Position der Fragezeichen einnimmt.

Comment: »Es gibt keinen Begriff in der Alltagssprache« wäre die richtige Antwort gewesen. Dem könnte man allfällige nicht-alltägliche Wörter anführen, und dabei deren Verwendungsgebiet beschrieben. Das Wort »anosmisch« fügt sich **nicht** in die rechte Spalte ein, denn es passt nicht zu *blind*, *taub* und *stumm*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Der Dissens rührt daher, dass der Titel der Frage und ihr erster Satz zwei unterschiedliche Fragen stellen. Em1s Antwort passt ohne weiteres zur Titelfrage, aber tatsächlich nicht gut zur zweiten.

Comment: @Em1: Ich habe die Antwort von knut akzeptiert, obschon deine durchaus korrekt ist und ich nicht explizit nach Alltagssprache gefragt habe (aber eigentlich eher solche gemeint habe - meine Nachlässigkeit).

Answer (score 4):

Nein. So ein Wort gibt es in der Alltagssprache nicht.

Den Fachbegriff *Anosmie/anosmisch* dürfte im Alltag kaum jemand verstehen.

Statt zwanghaft ein einzelnes Wort analog zu blind oder taub erfinden zu wollen, würde ich ganz einfach sagen:

> Ich kann nichts riechen.

oder

> Mein Geruchssinn streikt.

oder so.